# Can bushes help keep driveway and patio gravel stable?

Tags: drainage, landscaping, driveway, gravel, soil

My front yard has a U-shaped driveway on a significant slope. The arrows in the diagram below indicate the downward direction of the slope. From the bottom right to the top left, the elevation drops about 3'.

According to my design, there will be a level round patio in the middle.  The patio and the driveway will be covered with two distinct species of gravel. On the low side, there will be a quarter-circle retaining wall supporting the patio. On the high side, the patio will flow into the driveway. But in-between, there will be a 2'-wide sloped strip that spans the two elevations.

My question is: if I planted bushes on that strip, can they serve as a separator between the patio and the driveway? Would they keep the patio gravel contained in the patio? Would they help keep the stope on the strip stable? And can they be planted on a slope to begin with?

[image]

Comment: this seems to be a question about gardening/landscapinmg maybe ask here: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is an area of direct contact between the patio and driveway, the bushes won't serve as a separator (between your "two distinct species of gravel") there. They will not, of themselves, "contain" the patio gravel, either - it can be kicked into them easily. For both of those reasons I would suggest some sort of "hardscape" (brick, paver, etc) edge completely encircling the patio to serve those functions. At minimum an edging strip.

Bushes will help to stabilize the slope and can certainly be planted on a slope. Choose the right (fruiting) bushes and they can also provide a snack at certain times of the year.

Comment: I would say it depends on the Bush my mom has a row of box wood bushes or hedge that is quite dense and in that case it Has both kept people from walking across the yard and made a separation from bark to rock. I don’t know if they have a specific type or my step dad keeps them trimmed but they are only ~2’ high after 40? Years and animals (cats and dogs) go around because they are quite thick. But I like the idea of fruit bearing.

Comment: What's an example of a fruit beading bush?